# looking for the jar file for HexUtils. bytesToHex

Tags: jar

I have to implement the below code in my Java application, but I am unable to find the jar file for `HexUtils.bytesToHex()`. Where do I find that?

```
byte[] data =  cleartext.getBytes(ENCODING);
md.update(data);
byte[] digestedByteArray = md.digest();   
// Convert digested bytes to 2 chars Hex Encoding   
md5String = HexUtils.bytesToHex(digestedByteArray) );
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that I got what does this code , but seems the same can be done with help of  org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex.encodeHexString(final byte[] data) (commons-codec-*.jar). This one very easy to find